# inflate view in adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-adapter

In my code I have this condistion. If inmobi ads reqeust is success show inmoby ads if failed show Google Ads.

Here is my code

```
@Override
  public View getView(int positionInList, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (adsFreq != 0 && positionInList > 0 && (positionInList + 1) % adsFreq == 0) {
      mConvertView = convertView;
      if (mConvertView == null) {
        mConvertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.banner_inmobi_container,parent,false);
      }
      IMBanner bannerAdView = (IMBanner)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.bannerView);
      AdUtils.getInstance().loadInMobiBanner(bannerAdView, new IAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFail() {
          mConvertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.banner_container, parent, false);
          AdView mAdView = (AdView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
          mAdView.loadAd(AdUtils.getAdmobRequestForCurrentUser());
        }
      });
      return mConvertView;
    }
}
```

When InMobi request is successfully inmob ads shows but when I get request failed GoogleAds now showing at all.

For the test I put this code all alone and it's worked as well.

```
mConvertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.banner_container, parent, false);
          AdView mAdView = (AdView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
          mAdView.loadAd(AdUtils.getAdmobRequestForCurrentUser());
```

So what I did wrong here when load failed google ads not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to do it this way:

```
  private AdRequest adRequest;

  adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

  IMBanner bannerAdView = (IMBanner)mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.bannerView);
  AdView mAdView = (AdView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
  adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  AdUtils.getInstance().loadInMobiBanner(bannerAdView, new IAdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFail() {
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. but it's not my problem... My problem is it's now showing when called onFailed

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to run it inside getView. `getView()` method will run quite frequently every time you scroll. Instead, run it outside of the `getView()` and attach the result into a boolean variable.

Later in the `getView()` you can that boolean variable to determine which view you want to inflate to show, or show nothing.